# Folding only applications

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

The `fold` tactic replaces all occurrence of a term with another, so `fold (id f)` tries to replace all occurrences of `f` with `(id f)`.

However, I want to only fold `f` if it occurs in the context `(f [ ])`, not if it occurs in the context `([ ] f)`. In particular `repeat myfold (id f)`, should not loop.

Is there a general way to do this type of folding? The best I have right now is

```
repeat match goal with
| |- context [(f ?x)] => change (f x) with ((id f) x)
end
```

But the above does not work for contexts of the form `forall x, f x = f x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an intermediate value not containing `f`.  Something like

```
let f' := fresh in
pose (id f) as f';
change f with f'
change (id f') with f'; (* undo the change in locations where we've already added id *)
subst f'.
```

**Edit**

If you actually want to just fold things in applicative contexts, you can use three intermediate values, like this:

```
(* Copyright 2018 Google LLC.
   SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0 *)
Ltac myfold_id f :=
  let id_f := fresh in
  let id_f_good := fresh in
  let f' := fresh in
  pose (id f) as id_f;
  pose (id f) as id_f_good;
  pose f as f';
  repeat (change f with id_f at 1;
          lazymatch goal with
          | [ |- context[id_f _] ] => change id_f with id_f_good
          | _ => change id_f with f'
          end);
  subst id_f id_f_good f'.
Goal let f := id in (f = f, f 0) = (f = f, f 0).
Proof.
  intro f.
  (* (f = f, f 0) = (f = f, f 0) *)
  myfold_id f.
  (* (f = f, id f 0) = (f = f, id f 0) *)
```

Comment: This prevents looping, but will will still change `(g f)` into `(g (id f))`

Comment: Updated to not change `g f` to `g (id f)`.